# How to get all not exist keys after JsonConvert DeserializeObject in Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hello I'm using NewtonSoft Json.Net to deserialize my json data. I usually deserialize json string but I want to check all of not exist keys.

For example here is a json data.

```json
{
    "Hp": 100,
    "PlayerInfo": {
        "Atk": 10,
        "Def": 20
    },
    "Mp": 100
}
```

And I have a structure which can match above data.

```cs
[Serializable]
public struct CharaData
{
    public int Hp;
    
    [Serializable]
    public struct PlayerInfoData
    {
       public int Atk;
       public int Def;
       public int Spd; 
    }
    PlayerInfoData PlayerInfo;
}
```

And I'm gonna deseialize it like this.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharaData>(jsonStr);
```

- There is a `Mp` key in json data but in structure there is not.
- And in `PlayerInfoData` there is no `Spd` key in json data but in structure there is a `Spd` field.

  - *Well... Spd field seems initialize as a default 0 value and it could potentially be a bug.*

So I want to check what keys are not in structure.
And what structure fields are not deserialized because of not exist.

I will do my best to prevent these happening, but if some keys are missing in the process of deserializing from json data, I will log to find the problem why deserialize wasn't
completely success.

```
[Error][CharaData::Mp key not exist in json string]
[Error][CharaData::PlayerInfo::Spd field not exist in struct]
```

Seems there is no any method to check it in JsonConvert class.
I saw

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
```

but this does not check all of keys.
Is this need to write a custom json converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is twofold:

1. Find the missing fields
2. Find the extra fields

Before we are digging into the details let's split the `CharaData` into two classes

```
[Serializable]
public class CharaData
{
    public int Hp;
    public PlayerInfoData PlayerInfo;
}

[Serializable]
public class PlayerInfoData
{
    public int Atk;
    public int Def;
    public int Spd;
}
```

#### Missing Fields

This solution relies on the [JsonSchema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)

```
private static Lazy<JSchema> schema = new Lazy<JSchema>(() => {
    var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
    return generator.Generate(typeof(CharaData));
}, true);

public static void ReportMissingFields(string json)
{
    var semiParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
            
    try
    {
        semiParsed.Validate(schema.Value);
    }
    catch (JSchemaValidationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ValidationError.Message);
    }
}
```

- `schema` stores the json schema of `CharaData` in a lazy fashion
- `Validate` compares the `json` against the schema and if there is a mismatch then it throws a [`JSchemaValidationException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchemaValidationException.htm)

  - It exposes a property which type is [`ValidationError`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_ValidationError.htm) which contains a lots of information about the mismatch

#### Extra fields

This solution relies on [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm)

```
[Serializable]
internal class CharaDataExtras: CharaData
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> ExtraFields;
}

...

public static void ReportExtraFields(string json)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharaDataExtras>(json);
    foreach (var field in result.ExtraFields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An extra field has found, called {field.Key}");
    }
}
```

- I've defined the `CharaData` as class to be able to derive from it << `CharaDataExtras`
- Every extra field will be put into the `ExtraFields` dictionary

#### Usage

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
ReportMissingFields(json);
ReportExtraFields(json);
```

The output:

```
Required properties are missing from object: Spd.
An extra field has found, called Mp
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharaData>(jsonStr);

var mp=result.Mp;
var playerInfo=result.PlayerInfo;
```

if you want to know what key are exist just check them for null. By default all keys are null. if they are not null, it means they took value from json. For example you can use this code

```
if (mp==null) Console.WriteLine ("mp is not exist in json");
```

another way is to use reflection to check all properties

```
    var props = result.GetType().GetProperties();
    var nulls = new List<string>();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var propInstance = prop.GetValue(result, null);

        if (propInstance == null) nulls.Add(prop.Name);

        if (prop.Name == "PlayerInfo")
        {
            var prps = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties();
            foreach (var prp in prps)
                if (prp.GetValue(propInstance, null) == null) nulls.Add(prop.Name+"."+prp.Name);
        }

    }
    foreach (var n in nulls)
        Console.WriteLine(n + " doesn't have value");
```

test result

```
PlayerInfo.Spd doesn't have value
```

classes

```
public class PlayerInfo
    {
        public int? Atk { get; set; }
        public int? Def { get; set; }
        public int? Spd { get; set; } 
    }

    public class CharaData
    {
        public int? Hp { get; set; }
        public PlayerInfo PlayerInfo { get; set; }
        public int? Mp { get; set; }
    }
```