# HttpRequest.ReadFromJsonAsync does not throw error for JSON that does not match the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am testing out minimal-api's on .NET 6 and run into some strange behavior where the deserialization of the JSON content in the request never fails as long as it is a well-formed JSON document. The documentation for the method says it will throw an error if *"the request's content-type is not a known JSON type"*, but it never does...? Am I missing something basic here?

I have a simple model class *Message*:

```cs
public record Message
{
   public string Receiver { get; set; } = "";
   public string Content { get; set; } = "";
}
```

I add an endpoint like this:

```
app.MapPost("/send", async (http) =>
{
    var msg = await http.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<Message>()

    if (msg is not null)
    {   
        http.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        await http.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { Message = msg });
    }
    else
    {
        http.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        await http.Response.WriteAsync("Something went wrong...");
    }
});
```

If I use for example Postman and post a request with the following random JSON body:

```
{
    "qwe":"poasd",
    "wer":"alkøsjda",
    "hwata":"lkjasdfl",
    "lkjdfgkljhdf":"5678"
}
```

the API returns a HTTP 200 with:

```
"message": 
{
   "receiver": "",
   "content": ""
}
```

Why doesn't it throw an exception?

Comment: What you're looking for is called _schema validation_. I don't have an answer for your specific question, but perhaps you can find more information using this term.

Comment: `ReadFromJsonAsync` doesn't return `nul`l. you can check the properties `msg.Receiver` and `msg.Content` instead of checking `msg` as `null`

Comment: If you are using Newtonsoft for json handling then please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023956/how-to-get-all-not-exist-keys-after-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-in-json-net/70032194#70032194) where I detail how to find missing and extra fields.

Comment: Thank you all, that clears up my misunderstanding. Now that I read the method comments again I see it clearly states it will throw an error if the request's *content-type* is not a known JSON type. 

I suppose manual checks or schema validation is the best way forward.